# Starting a project on google code: where is download tab?

Tags: google-code

I started an open source project on google code. I've seen in other google code projects Downloads tab where I suppose to upload my files. I need to share a Liferay project and I prefer in this phase to share a zip/war file (Liferay bundles with source code): is it possible to do this? How it is possible to create Downloads tab? Do I need to use mercurial, svn or git also for this step?

Comment: You can put project downloads in Google Drive... https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/DownloadsFAQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, but [Google Code no longer supports downloads](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2013/05/a-change-to-google-code-download-service.html) for new projects. The download links you've seen are for older projects that were grandfathered in, but those projects also will no longer be able to create new downloads starting next January.